# How to properly index Sitecore 7 content in Solr with partial language fallback?

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I have a Sitecore 7.5 site that uses Solr 4.7 as the search engine.  It works great.  This is a multi-language site.  I am also using the Partial Language Fallback module written by Alex Shyba.  I have adapted it to work with Sitecore 7.5 and it works well.  The last part that I can't figure out is how to get the Solr search to work with partial language fallback.  I am guessing that what I need to do is somehow at indexing time I need to index the content for all languages and pull field values from the fallback language as necessary.  So let's say that I have the following:

- The site has 4 languages (English, Spanish, French, German)
- a Contact Us Page with 3 fields (Title, Subtitle, Content)
- There is an English version of the Contact Us page
- There is a Spanish version of the Contact Us page with all 3 fields filled out in Spanish
- There is a French version of the Contact Us page that only has the Content field filled out in French
- There is no German version of the Contact Us page

The Partial Language Fallback module handles this scenario perfectly.  No matter what language is the current context language, I still see the Contact Us page and all of the fields on the page.

But I'm not sure how I should have Solr index this content.  My guess is that somehow I need to tell Solr when it indexes to create a full index of the Contact Us page in all 4 languages and use the English content for each field if there is no content in that language.  I found [a blog post online](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/elizabeth-spranzani/posts/2014/10/fallback-followup.aspx) that showed how to do this for Lucene.  But I'm not sure how I would do this with Solr.  Does anyone know how to handle this in Solr?